# protractor switch from iframe to default content

Tags: javascript, iframe, webdriver, protractor

I'm trying to minimize a iframe form and post that i want to start working on my normal page. But, when i try to switch to default content browser redirects to raw page like :data.

`browser.switchTo().frame(iframeLiveChat).then(function(){
      console.log("i have entered frame");
      driver.findElement(by.xpath(".//*[@id='title']")).click().then(function(){
        console.log("i have clicked button");
        browser.switchTo().defaultContent();
//After this line the browser redirects itself to :data page instead of the url it has in it.
        });
    });`
Not able to switch back to the default content.

Answer (score 3):

Did you tried to not put your switch to callback?

```
browser.switchTo().frame(iframeLiveChat).then(()=> console.log("i have entered frame"))
element(by.xpath(".//*[@id='title']")).click().then(()=> console.log("i have clicked button"))
browser.switchTo().defaultContent();
```